# How can use coupon code to minus value from total price

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

**This is my html part where I use coupon input**

**IF need more code I'll provide**

```
Enter Coupon Code 



<input type="text" class="form" name="couponadd" id="couponadd" placeholder="Enter Your Coupon Code" oninput="myFunction()" style="width: -moz-available;" />
```

**Oninput I am getting the coupon code in script**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var getcoupon = document.getElementById("couponadd").value;
 var aftercoupn=0;
```

**if coupon code is gold then less 15 from total**

```
 if(getcoupon == 'gold')
 {
 var aftercoupn = 15;
 document.getElementById("aftercoupan").innerHTML = '- $' + aftercoupn;
 alert('minus 15 dollers');
 }
```

**if coupon code is silver then less 10 from total**

```
 else if(getcoupon == 'silver')
 {
  var aftercoupn = 10;
 document.getElementById("aftercoupan").innerHTML = '- $' +  aftercoupn;
  alert('minus 10 dollers');
 }
 else
 {
 }

}
</script>
```

**Iam getting price from php code loop**

```
echo  "<ul id='sub'>";
if($Seats == null){ 
echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
}
elseif($ticketType=='PINK' && $ticketType == $_GET['type']){
echo '<li class="pink" id="pink" data-price="100" title="Row'.$Seats.'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$Seats.'"></li>';
}

else{
echo '<li class="orange" id="orange" data-price="200" title="Row'.$Seats.'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$Seats.'"></li>';
}

}

echo "</ul>";
```

**script code  from get price on click of li**

```
var total =0;
var counter = 0;
var price=0;
$('li').click(function(e) {
var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
if click something
{
counter++;
}else
{
counter --;
}
```

**how can i use coupon code value here in total**

```
var total = parseFloat(price * counter);
document.getElementById('demoPrice').innerHTML = '$' + total;
}
});
```

Comment: save ` aftercoupn` value in `input` hidden field and fetch when you want to use

Comment: @Pritamkumar iam getting the coupon code with oninput function.so when coupon enter it minus some price from total

Comment: @Pritamkumar thenafter?

Comment: I hope you have coupon checking server-side too, otherwise anyone can look in the HTML and help themselves to discounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `aftercoupn` variable on text input, then use it on li's on click like

```js
var total = 0;
var counter = 0;
var price = 0;
var aftercoupn = 0;
$('li').click(function(e) {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
  if (price) { // I'm not sure with the counter variable here
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
  var total = parseFloat(price * counter);
  $('#demoPrice').text('$' + (total-parseInt(aftercoupn)));
});

function myFunction() {
  var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val(),
      txt='Invaild Coupon';
  if (getcoupon == 'gold') {
    aftercoupn = 15;
    txt = '- $' + aftercoupn;
    console.log('minus 15 dollers');
    counter=0;
  } else if (getcoupon == 'silver') {
    aftercoupn = 10;
    txt = '- $' + aftercoupn;
    console.log('minus 10 dollers');
    counter=0;
  }
  $('li.active').length && $('li.active').trigger('click');
  $("#aftercoupan").text(txt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form" name="couponadd" id="couponadd" placeholder="Enter Your Coupon Code" oninput="myFunction()" style="width: -moz-available;" />
<div id="aftercoupan"></div>
<ul id='sub'>
  <li class="BlankSeat" data-price="0">Blank</li>
  <li class="pink" id="pink" data-price="100" title="Row10" name="pink" value="10">Pink</li>
  <li class="orange" id="orange" data-price="200" title="Row20" name="orange" value="20">Orange</li>
</ul>
<div id="demoPrice"></div>
```

Comment: when first time click on li and price added in demo price (total).then after i enter the coupon code  then it is not minus the old total it minus new click price  only.but it should also minus the old total ..thats the problem sir

Comment: once coupon code entered price should be minus on every click ,in snippet first time click on pink ,price added and after coupon code it minus 15 from total but when again clicking on pink ,price again 100 it should be 85 every time someone clicks after coupon code

Comment: we can also use all total in %  and then 15 % minus from it

Comment: sir could you please tell me. if we write a php code with stmt-> or pdo classes ,is it safe? rather than any framework. very important for me because i don't know how to work with frameworks.so i am using Prepared Statements
stmt-> .

Comment: The code in my answer is not not related with PHP. And for PDO/MySQLi refer the links http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using price as a global variable. Then on click of `li` you should be updating that variable. So, you'll be able to have the price set on li click from other places ( I think that is what you're trying to achieve).

```
var total = 0, price, counter = 0;
$('li').click(function(e) {
  price = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
  // Do your other stuffs if you want
});
```

Then at other places you can get this price set after `li` click.

```
total = price * counter;
document.getElementById('demoPrice').innerHTML = '$' + total;
```

The whole thing is written in an assumption of your need. Correct me if I've thought it wrong or misunderstood somewhere